# Unity constructor parameters, with a twist

Tags: c#, .net, unity-container

I have this type of class hierarchy:

```
public interface IA{}

public interface IB{void Foo();}

public class A:IA
{
 [Dependency]
 IB myb{get;set;}

 void myfunc(){ myb.Foo()}
}

public class B:IB
{
 public B(IA ia){}
}
```

I want to make an instance of class A with Unity. 
But when I want to make it I would want to write something like this:

```
public Testclass
{   
 void TestMethod()
 {
  IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
  A currentA;
  container.RegisterType<IB,B>(new InjectionConstructor(currentA);
  currentA = container.Resolve<A>(); 
 }
}
```

This fails at the container.RegisterType line, saying that "Parameter type inference does not work for null values."

How to make this work?

Edit: Ahhhh how I hate this... Our Architect made two interfaces with the same name, and that's why I wasted 2 hours of my life. Daniel Hilgarth gave me a good idea, but I couldn't use it until I realised that resharper imported the wrong interface.

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your code and make it compilable! The code you provided is both unreadable and invalid.

Comment: of course it is not compilable, it's meta code. I just wrote it to represent my problem. It's completely readable on my computer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a circular dependency. That's bad. Either fix it or provide a factory for the creation of A.

Comment: I know I have circular dependency, but actually, without unity it is easy to do this in the constructor of A :

     public A(){myb = new B(this)}

Comment: It's just as easy in a factory: `A CreateA(){ A a = new A(); a.myb = new B(a); return a;}`

Comment: And where this CreateA should be?. A cannot see B, that's why Unity is needed.

Comment: Either you know `B` or you don't. If you know `B`, the factory is the solution. If you don't know `B`, you also don't know that it takes an a as a parameter to its constructor as this is an implementation detail. So in this case you don't have a problem either... I suggest you read about proper DI techniques, e.g. on [Mark Seemann's blog](http://blog.ploeh.dk/). If all implementations of  `IB` need an instance of `IA`, the API of `IB` should reflect this somehow.

Comment: I have actually a test class that tries to make an instance of A. It knows both A and B. I edited the first post a little

Answer (score 0):

In Ninject, you can defer some work by having your class implement `IInitializable`.  You could do something similar here.  In `Initialize`, you could fix up any dependencies that weren't possible during the constructor-based injection phase.

But, your question is not very clear.  You state a problem, but not the specific question.  Is it "why doesn't this work?", "should this work?", "can anyone suggest an alternative , strategy?", etc?